# Javascript Canvas images don't always load

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, canvas

Sometimes my images load the first time I visit the page and other times I have to refresh for them to load. Also sometimes one image will load and not the other.

```
//Store everything in arrays
var dimgs = ["hair-1", "head-1"]; //Name of classes for imgs
var cans = ["hairimg", "headimg"]; //Canvas element names
var dcans = ["chairimg", "cheadimg"]; //Canvas names
var dctxs = ["ctxa", "ctxb"]; //Context names
var defimgs = []; //Images found

//Loop to create Canvas and draw image
for (var p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
    if(p != null) {
       getcan(p);
    }
}

//Function to create Canvas and draw image
function getcan(p) {
    defimgs[p] = document.getElementsByClassName(dimgs[p])[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    var x;
    if(p != null) {
       defimgs[p].onload = (function(x){
          dcans[x] = document.getElementById(cans[x]);
          dctxs[x] = dcans[x].getContext('2d');
          dcans[x].width = defimgs[x].naturalWidth;
          dcans[x].height = defimgs[x].naturalHeight;
          dctxs[x].drawImage(defimgs[x], 0, 0);
       }(p));
    }
}
```

I've also tried the following with the same results:

```
//Store everything in arrays
var dimgs = ["hair-1", "head-1"]; //Name of classes for imgs
var cans = ["hairimg", "headimg"]; //Canvas element names
var dcans = ["chairimg", "cheadimg"]; //Canvas names
var dctxs = ["ctxa", "ctxb"]; //Context names
var defimgs = []; //Images found

//Loop to create Canvas and draw image
for (var p = 0; p < 2; p++) {
    if(p != null) {
       defimgs[p] = document.getElementsByClassName(dimgs[p])[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
       dcans[p] = document.getElementById(cans[p]);
       dctxs[p] = dcans[p].getContext('2d');
       dcans[p].width = defimgs[p].naturalWidth;
       dcans[p].height = defimgs[p].naturalHeight;
       getcan(p);
    }
}

//Function to draw image
function getcan(p) {
    var x;
    if(p != null) {
       defimgs[p].onload = (function(x){
          dctxs[x].drawImage(defimgs[x], 0, 0);
       }(p));
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <canvas id="hairimg" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
  <canvas id="headimg" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="hair-1"">
  <img src="hair.png" alt="User Image">
</div>
<div class="head-1"">
  <img src="head.png" alt="User Image">
</div>
```

I just don't know the proper way to load multiple images that are each in a `div` tag using the `div` class onto a `canvas`.

Comment: You are executing the function after `onload = ...`. So what you assign to onload it this function's returned value (`undefined`)  and your function is executed directly (hence probably before the image has loaded). Will try to find one of the many dupes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider using window.onload. This callback will only fire after all images on a page have finished loading, so processing your images at that point may be more successful. Here's a [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) with some more information, as well as [the documentation for window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload).

You'd structure it something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    dimgs.forEach(function(img) {
        getcan(img);
    });
}
```

Comment: Seems to work so far. Thank you!